# Magento Rollback

Tags: php, magento

This website belongs to a company I work for:

https://lcdtcorp.com/

Thing is that a few days ago, I installed a extension, and all of a sudden I got some weird message:

*There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 811276254152*

Through the backend, I was asked to "Rollback".

After that, the template was severely damaged. It does not look like that on my laptop, or inside my work computer.

So I uploaded nearly all the template files from my laptop, even the ones from pub and var, and app. In fact, I have uploaded files from all the directories.

The template still looks like crap. But it does not look like that in my laptop. I have flushed the cache several times already.

What's going on?

Comment: disable the extension & check once.... also if you have backup files & database, replace those & try.....

Comment: It was a file inside /pub/static that was causing the problem.

Comment: glad you found solution.....